# Any yii-way to update tag attributes via Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, yii

Say I have an ajax action which returns particular image url based on the params. I want to use ajax call to update a image tag with different images via ajax. The action looks like this:

```
public function actionSendUrl($params)
{
   echo IMAGE_PATHS[$params];
}
```

But when comes to `CHtml::ajaxButton` I found out that `CHtml::ajax` class only has a `update` or `replace` properties which just replace the whole text or entire tag with my reponse.

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton('BLAH','SendUrl?params=***',array('replace'=>'#image_tag_id'),);
```

which made to modify my action code to:

```
public function actionSendUrl($params)
{
   echo CHtml::image(IMAGE_PATHS[$params],array('id'=>'image_tag_id'));
}
```

What is pissing me is that I have to construct tag id everytime I change image, but the whole tag is also dissapear for a very short time so that the page stunts up and down while loading the new image. Is there any way to make `CHtml::ajax` to update `scr` instead of the whole tag?

Or I just pushed myself into writing real jQuery code in order to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cna do it by specifying a (custom written) jquery function in the success attribute of your ajax array, which updates the src. see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajax-detail

Something like this (but it really depends on your situation):

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton('BLAH','SendUrl?params=***',array( 
    'success'=>
        "function(return, status, jqXHR){
            if(status == 'success'){
                $('#image_tag_id').attr('src',return);
            }
       }"
    ),
);
```

You might want to check the ajax page for jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: I'm afraid I need some help on this one also, do you mean write sth like `'success'=>'function(data){....}'`. I need complete, working example. Thanks!

Comment: @GeRong I modified my answer.